# Getting error 406 while trying to send a file using socks5 with strophe.js

Tags: javascript, xmpp, strophe

I am very much new to JavaScript and XMPP and need to implement Socks5 to transfer files with Strophe.js

when i call the method below:

```
sendS5BInitiation: function (from ,to, sid, jid, host, port, cb) {

  var iq = $iq({
    from: from,
    id: sid,
    to: to,
    type: 'set'
  }).c('query', {
    xmlns: 'http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams',
    sid: sid ,
    mode: "tcp"       
  }).c('streamhost',{
    jid: jid,
    host: host,
    port: port
  });

  connection.sendIQ(iq,onSuccess,onError,60*1000);
}
```

I get 406 error as

```
<iq id="4023b2c8" to="dummy@myserver/4023b2c8" from="xyz@myserver/Spark 2.6.3" type="error"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams" sid="4023b2c8" mode = "tcp"><streamhost jid="dummy@myserver" host="182.148.1.200" port="7777"/></query><error code="406" type="MODIFY"><not-acceptable xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/></error></iq>
```

Please help me to get out of this problem.